# The IE cannot parse some German special characters

Tags: json, internet-explorer

I used jQuery.postJSON method to get a list of names, which contains such as "üd" characters, in Chrome, the returned JSON can be parsed correctly, but in IE, the json string will be broken, does anyone know how to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you might try to declare UTF8 encoding in your header.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

See how that goes...

Alternatively you may need to parse the json with utf8 specifically. But you havent mentioned what language / platform you are developing in.

e.g. `json.parseUTF8(myJSONString)` or similar.

Good luck.